# Block search engine for some specific word

Tags: html, search

Suppose I put a word "Abracadabra" on my webpage. Suppose someone, let us say, Mr. John Smith, searches the word "Abracadabra" Then my page can show up in his search result. But I do not want this. Although I do want my page to show up if he searches other word on my webpage. Please advise how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse user agents of visitors and display different content (without those keywords) to crawlers/search bots, but that could bring you some problems from Google, because they are really sensitive about displaying different content to robots than to other users.

Only 'legit' solution would be to Disallow bots from searching via robots.txt, but as you want page to be crawlable this isn't an option.

**So overall you can't "ban" specific keywords.**